# AWS CDK: How to encrypt StringParameter in SSM since type is deprecated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm

I'm trying to replace my secrets in SecretsManager with SSM Parameter Store to save on costs. I'm using CDK v2 and now the SSM.StringParameter `type` parameter [is deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html#typespan-classapi-icon-api-icon-deprecated-titlethis-api-element-is-deprecated-its-use-is-not-recommended%EF%B8%8Fspan).

I've seen another construct, [cdk-secure-string-parameter](https://constructs.dev/packages/cdk-secure-string-parameter/v/0.0.14?lang=typescript), but frankly, it's too new and seems overly complicated.

Is this possible any longer?

Comment: what is the use case? if you access your secret from lambda/ some code and this part is invoked a lot maybe you can "cache" the secret in your code instead of reading it every time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDK cannot create SSM Secure String Parameters directly.  This limitation [has always existed](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3520).  It is because [AWS CloudFormation doesn't support creating a SecureString parameter type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.CfnParameter.html#type).

A workaround is to use a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) to call the `PutParameter` API.  This is what the referenced ConstructHub construct [does](https://github.com/Saigonen/cdk-secure-string-parameter/blob/main/src/lambda/secure-string-parameter-handler.lambda.ts).

Comment: Thanks @fedonev. To clarify, I'm not trying to SET the secret value in the CDK — just creating the parameter itself. Just like secrets manager interface.

Comment: @Ryan  Glad to help. It doesn't matter that you don't need to set the value.  The CDK cannot create the parameter itself.