# How can I read and write secrets to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, aws-parameter-store

For context, I have tested out the solution mentioned here in https://sst.dev/chapters/handling-secrets-in-sst.html. The solution works, but I have to manually set the secrets on the command line. I would like to do the same using code, where I extract environmental variables and add them as secrets to AWS, which I will then bind to the various AWS Lambdas without the need for command line operations.

I have tried to replicate the writing of secrets to the AWS SSM Parameter Store with the AWS CDK StringParameter construct (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html). However, I am facing a roadblock where it appears that Parameters of type SecureString cannot be created directly from a CDK application (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.ParameterType.html). I tried to use the AWS Secrets Manager CDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html) to write the secrets as well, but it did not work out. Can I check if anyone has solved this issue before? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is often better to store secrets via the Command-Line rather than storing them "in code", which gets stored in repositories. That wouldn't keep them very 'secret'.

Comment: I don't intend to store the secrets in code; I intend to extract the variables from environmental variables and add them as secrets to AWS

Comment: Suspect you need to use Secrets Manager or a [custom resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75607168/aws-cdk-how-to-encrypt-stringparameter-in-ssm-since-type-is-deprecated).

Comment: It looks like it can't be done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75607394/13070 Which is surprising to me as a Terraform user, since this is a trivial task in Terraform.